# Android Emulator not working with local Asp.net web app when proxy is used

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi guyz
I have an asp.net mvc web application which has an Android client. I want to test the application on real device but the problem is the web application is not published yet.The application works fine on emulator where I use the 10.0.2.2 ip as localhost. 
The android Application needs internet for google maps.When I use proxy on emulator for the internet,which is needed, the web application is not accessed then i-e the 10.0.2.2 does not work. 
**Any idea on how can I connect android emulator with both web application and the internet. Also what should i do in case of real device?**

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that the proxy cannot access your local server, so if you want to test it through a proxy (unless is a local proxy), you have to publish the webapp on the internet